# tmux equivalent of "screen -R"?

Tags: tmux

The `tmux attach` command acts more like a combination of `screen -r` and `screen -x` -- first it trys to attach to the most recently *detached* session, and then if none is available it will attach to a currently attached session. I want to emulate the behavior of `screen -R`: first try to attach to a detached session, then start a new session if there were no detached sessions. What is the best way to achieve this in tmux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After consulting the wizards of IRC I am confident there is no single tmux command that has this behavior. Luckily, it is fairly easy to emulate using the shell:

```
(tmux ls | grep -vq attached && tmux at) || tmux
```

Comment: Minor edit to squelch the "failed to connect to server: Connection refused" output in the event that you're launching a new session:
`(tmux ls 2>/dev/null | grep -vq attached && tmux at) || tmux`

Answer (score 3):

Despite what it says in tmux manual:

```
             The target-session rules for attach-session are slightly
         adjusted: if tmux needs to select the most recently used session,
         it will prefer the most recently used unattached session.
```

Drew's answer won't work properly in a situation like:

```
0: 1 windows (created Wed Nov  7 23:51:08 2012) [177x47]
1: 1 windows (created Wed Nov  7 23:51:33 2012) [177x47] (attached)
```

`tmux at` will attach to the last session (#1) (even though this session is still attached somewhere else). This ruins the whole idea of running several tmux sessions and attaching only to a detached one (to use mosh + tmux + iterm2 to create a perfect roaming terminal).

Another approach would be to manually select a non-attached session:

`` tmux ls | grep -vq attached && tmux at  `tmux ls |  grep -vm1 attached | cut -d: -f1` ``

Comment: Good catch! The documentation is out of sync with the actual behavior. I created a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3590129&group_id=200378&atid=973262) for this.

Comment: A patch is out that fixes this, so by the next release it should behave as advertised.

Comment: Is the patch in 1.8?

Answer (score 3):

I tend to only have two tmux sessions at a time, so I do something like this in each terminal window.

terminal window 0:

```
tmux attach -t 0 || tmux new
```

terminal window 1:

```
tmux attach -t 1 || tmux new
```

Answer (score 2):

This has worked the best for me:

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
     (tmux ls | grep -vq attached && tmux at -t `tmux ls | grep -vm1 attached | cut -d: -f1`) || tmux new
fi
```

The -t is needed to attach to the proper session.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
tmux attach || tmux new
```

or instead just create the file `~/.tmux.conf` if it doesn't exist, and add

```
new-session
```

to it such that it creates a new session when there is none when you run `tmux attach`.

It might also be handy to make `tmux` an alias to `tmux attach`.

Comment: The first proposal would attach to currently attached tmux sessions (similar to screen -x), which is something I want to avoid. The second proposal exhibits this same problem and also has the undesirable consequence of creating "extra" tmux sessions when I use the tmux source-file command to reload the config.